# How could I create a python script so that I can enter Gmail and extract the content of an email with a specific subject?

Tags: python, seleniumbase

I need to create a script that enters Gmail and can extract the content and subject of an email with a specific subject (in python)

I would like you to help me with an example in python please

selenium base or another library for python

Comment: No, Selenium is absolutely the wrong way to do this.  Gmail supports an IMAP interface.  You can go search the emails directly, with no web scraping hackery required.

Comment: Show us the code you have written to address this problem, even if it does not yet achieve a solution.

Comment: i need to create rpa no web scrapping hackery